# Unit testing a Text Index

Tags: string, unit-testing, data-structures, indexing, googletest

Consider a text index such as a suffix tree or a suffix array supporting *Count* queries (number of occurrences of a pattern) and *Locate* queries (the positions of all the occurrences of a pattern). How   would you go about unit testing such a class ?

What I have in mind is to generate a *big* random string then extract a random substring from this big string and compare the results of both queries with naive implementations (such as string::find). Another idea I have is to find the most frequent substring of length `l` appearing in the original string (using perhaps a naive method) and use these substrings for testing the index.

This isn't the best way, so what would be a good design of the unit tests for a text index ?

In case it matters, this is in C++ using googletest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Count queries (number of occurrences of a pattern) and Locate queries (the positions of all the occurrences of a pattern) over a given text don't have to set an expectation on a method and instead you can just set a default return value.

So, Utilize `Mocks` and `Stubs` here.

Easy Examples, http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies

For further reference, http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook